# Rails - how to add css to a helper method

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, helper, view-helpers

Im trying to move a long if statement out of my view and into a helper method.

I currently have:

```
module ProfilesHelper
    def items_for_profile_menu(profile)
        if current_user = @profile.user_id 
      "<li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem" style="background:#006F7F">
               <a href="index.html" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
                       # link_to dashboard_path(@profile.dashboard) 
                      <span>Dashboard</span>
               </a>

        </li>

                <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem" style="background:#39AFBF">
                     <a href="#resume" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
                     <!-- <i class="flaticon-graduation61"></i> --><br><br>
                     <span>Timeline</span></a>
        </li>"

    <% else %>

                  "<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem orange">
                     <a href="#stats" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><i class="flaticon-placeholders4"></i><span>Impact</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem red">
                     <a href="#feedback" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><i class="flaticon-earphones18"></i><span>Feedback</span></a>
                  </li>"
               <% end %>

    end


end
```

Im getting stuck figuring out whether I can write css in the helper itself? If I can, how can I learn about the modifications required to get it working? In the view I was able to write: background:#006F7F in the list item. If I add that to the helper - then the # is received as a comment.

Can anyone see how to setup a helper method with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not terminating string properly in your code. One double quote (`"`) will terminate previous double quote (`"`). So your string is consider like `"<li class="` as one string and looking for `"` after that and you will get error if this is not the case.

So for declaring class inside a big string use single quotes (`'`) inside a big double quoted (`"`) string and concat each big string with (`+`).

To add class use single quote `"<li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem'>Hi </li>"` `+` `"<li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem'>Hello </li>"`

Change your code like below.

```
module ProfilesHelper
  def items_for_profile_menu(profile)
    if current_user = @profile.user_id 
      "<li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#006F7F'>
        <a href='index.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
          <span>Dashboard</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#39AFBF'>
        <a href='#resume' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
        <span>Timeline</span></a>
      </li>"
    else
      "<li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem orange'>
        <a href='#stats' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'><i class='flaticon-placeholders4'></i><span>Impact</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem red'>
        <a href='#feedback' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'><i class='flaticon-earphones18'></i><span>Feedback</span></a>
      </li>"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked to get the helper finished  but its definitely not the right way to make a helper - it has printed out the css e.g. <li>.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html_safe` for example:

```
def my_name
    name = "<h1>Eric Santos!</h1>"
    name.html_safe
 end
```

hope you get the idea!